# Print a tree in php from A database table but depending on permissions

Tags: php

I have a table in oracle every file is a level of a tree. A field parent on every file have the identifier of the superior level which is the parent
This is a very common estructure in tables for recursively print a tree hierarchy. 
Every elements can have one or more and so on.

So far is easy but now I must hide branches if at the end of a brach the last element, which is the last register in a the end is marked as not allowed (can be a field for example but only for the finals elements).

If at the end of a nested levels of branches all the finals elements are marked as no allowed to see then the parents elements must be hidden but if only one of the finals is allowed then the parent brach musn't be hidden.

Please anybody can help me on how print this kind of trees

Is something recursive but only at the end can realize which the levels must be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. But I know nothing about your structures...

We must assume that a leaf is "inherited" from a branch. This would generate the list of the authorized branches.

```
Function GenerateTree($CurrentBranch)
{
    $text = "";
    if ($CurrentBranch->isLeaf())
    {
       if ($CurrentBranch->isAuthorized())
         return "<li>" . $CurrentBranch->Text . "</li>";
       else
         return false;
    }
    Foreach ($CurrentBranch->Branches as $Branch)
    {
       $BranchText = GenerateTree($Branch);
       if ($BranchText !== false)
         $text .= $BranchText;
    }
    if ($text == "")
      return false;
    return "<ul>" . $text . "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Thank  you I'm going to  carefully review your solution. Other people told me about using  the specifics  sentences in  ORACLE SQL (server we are using).  The hierarchical sentences. If necessary i'll print here my data model